# Spark and Java: Error ClassCastException

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-spark

I am following exactly this example 
https://github.com/rathboma/hadoop-framework-examples/tree/master/spark
When I try to run, I get this message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.api.java.Optional cannot be cast to com.google.common.base.Optional
```

I do not how can I fix it, because I am newbie using Spark. 
Thanks!!
Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like you imported the wrong Optional class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you use Spark 1.x to compile codes but run your application in Spark 2.x cluster. You can update `pom.xml` to use the same version of your Spark cluster and probably need to update your codes as well because 2.x and 1.x are not compatible.

Comment: How do you know the cluster version?

Comment: I have installed Spark 2.1.1 using this file spark-2.1.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz  and then, I have connected Spark with the Hadoop installation setting the spark-env.sh file in /usr/local/spark/conf (I followed this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-provided.html). 
Can I change this part in pom.xml?         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version> And it could be work?

Comment: @cricket_007 Print `SparkContext.version`

Comment: @majitux yeah, you need to change it. However, you probably also need to update codes because Spark 2.x breaks source compatibility. That's why you see ClassCastException when using different versions.

Comment: I meant, from the question and error , how did you guess the cluster version

Comment: @cricket_007 Just because I happened to review the change from `com.google.common.base.Optional` to `org.apache.spark.api.java.Optional` :)